# Why doesn't an electron's charge rip the electron apart?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, charge, coulombs-law

Like charges repel.

1. What keeps an electron's charge from repelling itself?  This problem would come up if an electron was divisible and its parts had fractional charge.
2. A related question is, what keeps an electron from being divisible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If like charges repel, why doesn't a charge break itself apart?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268818/)

Comment: Although this is the earlier question, I have voted to close it in favour of  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268818, which has more answers which are more highly developed.

Comment: I'm voting to keep it open because all the answers in the alleged duplicate are wrong. The electron is not a point particle. Dmckee will [back me up on that](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268464/76162). It's quantum field theory. Not quantum point-particle theory.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to the other question.  I'm interested in the case where the particle ("the electron") does not have any constituents.  It's all right by me to close this question, etc., if the answer is discussed over there.

Answer (score 4):

There is no structure of electrons as far as we know. It's a point entity. So it cannot be seen as something that has further structure or said to be having "parts". It's a fundamental particle