# How is wavelength defined for standing waves?

Tags: waves, wavelength, harmonics

How is wavelength defined for standing waves? I cannot understand why the first harmonic is half a wavelength rather than a full wavelength. I see how wavelength is defined for progressive waves but I cannot apply this to standing waves.

Comment: if it were a full wavelength it would be the same and not a harmonic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic

Comment: The wavelength is defined in the same way as for running waves. Just to make sure you know what a standing wave is, see [this animation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268472/21441). It would be confusing if the definition of wavelength changed just because you have a superposition of two running waves of the same wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

A standing wave is the sum of two waves with wave numbers $k_1$ and $k_2$, with the condition that:

$$ k_1 = -k_2 $$

so we'll say:

$$k = ||k_1|| = ||k_2|| $$

The wavelength is then:

$$ \lambda = \frac{2\pi}k$$

A full wavelength has 3 nodes (inclusive) and 2 anti-nodes. You only need 2 nodes to get a standing wave on a string, so the length is $\lambda/2$.